# Is it possible to extend the Spotipy library to include audio books?

Tags: spotify, spotipy

Spotipy python library only includes music data, not audiobooks

I would love to get top audiobooks trending, and other "popular" metrics just like the music data. Such as most popular titles, authors, avg duration, bounce rate, sort by price, etc.

Comment: Spotipy is a Spotify Web API wrapper. This means it's limited to the API of Spotify. The functionality of what you describe is not covered by any public API of Spotify. For further feature requests, I suggest you to put them at [its GitHub page](https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy) directly as an _Issue_, and choosing for _Feature Request_.